# How to show another website without its header in a certain website using only html?

Tags: html, web, iframe

I want to show a certain part of a page in another one using only html.
The website is: http://alojamientos.rumboalsur.es
And the part is:
[image]

I have tried using an IFrame and trying to select the div class where it is but the whole page keeps showing up.
The code I am trying is:

```
<iframe src="http://alojamientos.rumboalsur.es/#nav-drawer" width="1920" height="1080" align="center" ></iframe>
```

The div class I am using is: nav-drawer
[image]

Am I using the wrong div class? Is there any other way of doing it using html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible for you to alter another domain inside of an iframe because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). So there is no way with HTML/CSS or JavaScript to alter the content of another domain.